# visual studio remote debugging issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

Local machine: VS 2013 update 5 Win 8.1 Pro 64 bits
Remote machine: VS Remote monitor 2013 update 4 (there was no update 5 on the download site) Win 7 Professional 64 bits

I was able to get a list of processes via `Debug -> Attach to process` menu in VS - no domain trifling, just used the means of IP:PORT - however when I click onto a process to attach to from the remote host I get the

`Unable to attach to process. (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer`

I went through the issue list at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164726.aspx

and the only things that I could not figure were:

> > The local and remote machines have different authentication modes

how do I check ?

and

> > The version of the remote debugger doesn’t match the version of Visual Studio

there is no update 5 version available for the Remote Monitor tool.

Any idea what could be going on ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am always using the remote debugger from VS directory (in my case it is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\`)

If it is possible I disable firewall on remote machine (temporarily for the time I am debugging).

I connect to the remote machine using IP only (I am not specifying any port. It will use default). VS will then ask to input credentials of a remote user. If it is possible I use some administrator account.